# Presenter show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've started moving all my view logic to presenters and I'm getting the following error `NameError at /bids
uninitialized constant Bid::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxyPresenter` on my index view. The presenter works in all my other views for this model except index. I've added commented code of fixes I've tried.

Code:

Index view:

```
<% present @bids do |bid_presenter| %>

<% end %>

# tried @bids to match controller
# <% present @bids do |bid_presenter| %>
# <% end %>
```

bid_presenter.rb:

```
class BidPresenter < BasePresenter
    presents :bid

    # tried :bids
    # presents :bids
end
```

base_presenter.rb:

```
class BasePresenter
    def initialize(object, template)
        @object = object
        @template = template
    end

private

    def self.presents(name)
        define_method(name) do
            @object
        end
    end

    # h method returns the template object
    def h
        @template
    end

    def method_missing(*args, &block)
        @template.send(*args, &block)
    end
end
```

bids_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @bids = current_user.bids
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<% @bids.each do |bid| %>
 <% present bid do |bid_presenter| %>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The Presenter is presenting an instance of the model; your code is trying to present an ActiveRecord::Collection or something.

Comment: I see! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.